# Force subselect fetch in collection

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a hibernate bean mapped like this:

```
class Consulta{

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Orden.class)
        @JoinTable(name = "cons_ords",
                joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "con_id") },
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ord_id")}
        )
        @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        private Set<Orden> ordenes;

}
```

then I'm fetching a limited number of element, lets say 5,

```
Criteria criteria = ...;
criteria.createAlias("ordenes", "ordenes", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
criteria.setFetchSize(5);
criteria.setMaxResults(5);
return criteria.list();
```

but because of the @ManyToMany, or the JoinType, idk, hibernate is making a join and "duplicating" the elements in the result, and once I check the returned list, there are less elements than the requested(5), and my pagination is falling bringing less elements per page than requested,

I'm indicating the fetch mode in LAZY and indicating the SUBSELECT, but the final query ends up with a JOIN,

```
select
    this_.id, orden2_.id, ...
from
    Consulta this_ 
left outer join     <------
    cons_ords ordcons11_ 
        on this_.ID = ordcons11_.con_id 
left outer join     <------
    Orden orden2_ 
        on ordcons11_.ord_id = orden2_.ID 
where
    ...
```

is there another way to map and force it to be a subselect? or indicate a custom strategy for counting elements when you se a fetch size?

**EDIT 1:**

these are my tables:

```
Consulta         cons_ords                  Orden
+----+           +-----------------+        +-----+
| ID |           | CON_ID | ORD_ID |        | ID  |
+----+           +-----------------+        +-----+
|  1 |           |  1     |   101  |        | 101 |
|  2 |           |  2     |   101  |        | 102 |
|  3 |           |  2     |   102  |        | 103 |
|  4 |           |  3     |   105  |        | 104 |
|  5 |           |  5     |   103  |        | 105 |
|  6 |           +--------+--------+        | 106 |
+----+                                      | 107 |
                                            +-----+
```

as suggested by @Chris, I tried to remove the JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, but doing so, only elements 1, 2, 3 and 5 are are returned, instead of fetching 1-5,

at the moment the problem is that the query is bringing  (1, 2, 2, 3, 4) that's the query as printed in console and executed, once it is turned into java objects, the List only have 4 elements, 1, 2, 3, 4, because its removing "duplicated" elements as it should do.

**EDIT 2:**

as mentioned in edit 1, the *criteria.createAlias("ordenes", "ordenes", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);* is forcing the JOIN instead of the subselect,

changing to only *criteria.createAlias("ordenes", "ordenes");* fall into the default inner join and makes the number of elements returned to be less than it should,

the current solution, if it can be called that is to condition that line like so:

```
if (restrictions.stream().anyMatch(
                c -> c instanceof InExpression && ((InExpression) c).toString().startsWith("ordenes.")))
criteria.createAlias("ordenes", "ordenes", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

this way, only if you explicitly are adding a constraint involving the that sub element of the bean, the join will be included accordingly, I don't like this solution and I see future implications, but for the moment it works. I still think that no matter the join type your setting, hibernate should prioritize fetch type lazy.

Comment: Why are you manually adding createAlias("ordenes", "ordenes", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN); to your query? That is forcing the join to be added into your query exactly as you've specified, overriding your mapping's fetch annotation. Remove it and you might get what you are expecting

Comment: @Chris yeah but if I don't add the OUTER LEFT, then the elements that don't have reference to the other table, are not included, and I got less elements in the list

Comment: I can't see what your query is, but you can't eat your cake and have it too. If you add 'ordenes' as something you need fetched and returned in the direct query results, you have to take that into account with the pagination. My understanding of your initial prob description and the mapping you've provided though is that Orden will be fetched, just after the main query to fetch your main entity. I would guess that your issue really is with the 'lazy' fetching on your collection and that you are not triggering this collection on returned entities - is that it? Maybe try specifying a load graph

Comment: @Chris the pagination is for Consulta, I'm fetching X elements of that table. I cannot know it the list of elements in each row has or doesn't has elements, that's  why I need that join not to be there, and once hibernate has the 5 elements of Consulta, THEN go fetch its sub-elements in subsequent queries,  is that or tho tell hibernate that when you bring me X number of row take in consideration the duplicated row by id and not only rowindex,

Comment: What is the query when you remove your join, and why was there a orden2_.id being fetched in the SQL you showed if you aren't adding it as a fetch? You may need to rework your query so that you use a subselect and perform the join within the subquery so that the duplicates caused by the join don't affect the actual results.